# How to show a link with Extjs 4?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4

This is the href i have set to display none

```
<a href="#" target="_self" alt="" id="company"><div></div></a>

#company div {
    position: relative;
    width: 450px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url(../images/logo.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: none;
}
```

i want to show this with extjs once the application is loaded.

so i try something like this but doesnt seems to work

```
var el = Ext.get('company');
el.show();
```

any idea how to show this once needed?

Regards

**solved:** by removing **display: none;** from this and added display: none; to

```
#company{
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Where you want to show the link, GridPanel, Container,  or Window ??

Comment: i figure out what i was doing wrong. i was hiding div inside of href and trying to show href which isn't actually hidden

Comment: If it is fixed, post solution as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove display: none; from current css

and add display none to the href instead of div

```
#company{
display: none;
}
```

then with extjs call below line when you want to display link

```
Ext.get('company').show();
```